# Debugging a forEach loop to understand how it works

Tags: javascript, foreach, iteration

I would love your help on the following simple exercise.
I'm learning forEach but I'm not sure where's the bug. Tried in multiple ways
to solve it, but still getting error.

My objective would be to run through the array phoneBook and display on the
page the corresponding name and number.

Example: if I search "Fede", I should get as a result "Fede1234"

```js
var phoneBook = [{
  name: "Fede",
  number: "1234"
}, {
  name: "Marco",
  number: "5678"
}]

phoneBook.forEach(search(name))

function search(name) {
  if (name === phoneBook.name) {
    document.write(phoneBook.name + phoneBook.number)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The first parameter to `forEach` is supposed to be a function, you're using the return value of `search` which is not a function.

Comment: Also, there doesn't seem to be any `name` variable.

Comment: Replace `phoneBook.forEach(search(name))` with `phoneBook.forEach(search)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things going on here. On this line: `phoneBook.forEach(search(name))` the variable `name` is not defined. if you want to pass in each object, the line should be:

`phoneBook.forEach(search)`

This will automatically pass each object to the search function.

the search function itself also has a few issues:

```
function search(name) {
  if (name === phoneBook.name) {
      document.write(phoneBook.name + phoneBook.number)
  }
}
```

In this case, `name` is the entire object. Also, since `phonebook` is the array, calling `phonebook.name` wont return anything.

Try this:

```
var phoneBook = [{name: "Fede" , number: "1234"}, {name: "Marco" , number: "5678"}]
var name = "Fede";
phoneBook.forEach(search)

function search(object) {
  if (name === object.name) {
  document.write(object.name + object.number)
  }
}
```

Now, `name` is defined, and the search function is being applied to each object in the phonebook.

Answer (score 1):

```
var phoneBook = [{name: "Fede" , number: "1234"}, {name: "Marco" , number: "5678"}]
phoneBook.forEach(search);

function search(name) {
  if (name === "???") {
    document.write(phoneBook.name + phoneBook.number)
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Intro

To learn [forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), understand the syntax:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue [, index [, array]]) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

As you can see the callback function has two more parameters: beside the value there are index of that value and the array itself. There is also a second argument to forEach itself, which can set context (useful when iterating something in object).

#### Level 1

If you want to use forEach to search a value, the search function has to return callback function (we call this construct [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)):

```
phoneBook.forEach(search("Fede"))

function search(name) {
  return function(value, position) {
    if (name === value.name) {
      document.write(value.name + value.number);
      document.write(" found at position "+position);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Level 2

Or you can (ab)use the thisArg forEach parameter:

```
phoneBook.forEach(search,"Fede")

function search(value) {
  if (this == value.name) { // Fede was passed to this
    document.write(value.name + value.number);
  }
}
```

Note the `==` operator instead `===`: Fede was passed as object String, but value.name is just string literal here (different type).

For that purpose, however, you should use [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), where the callback accepts the same arguments:

```
function search(value) {
  return this == value.name;
}
var fede = phoneBook.find(search,"Fede");

if(fede) document.write(fede.name + fede.number);
```

#### Level 3

While you are learning, for such simple one-liner function there are more convenient [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are a little bit different, context can't be passed by find or forEach method, for example. Yet, you can further simplify the search to single line:

```
var fede = phoneBook.find(value => "Fede" === value.name);
```